# sort file but keep pairs of lines together

Tags: sort

I have a file, with entries of the structure

```
a1;b1;c1;
d1;e1;f1;g1
a2;b2;c2;
d2;e2;f2;g2
```

etc.

I want to sort this file via the g's, but keep the abc's with the corresponding g. 
Is there any nice way of doing this via the command line? All I can think of right now is to write a more or less elaborate perl script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your lines are guaranteed to come in pairs with three fields on the first and 4 on the second (and the second line contains the "g" value):

```
$ sed -n 'N;s/\n//;p' your_file \
   | sort -t';' -k7 \
   | perl -F';' -ane '$,=";";print @F[0..2],"\n";print @F[3..$#F]'
```

The `sed` part joins together every two consecutive lines, `sort` sorts the input on the seventh field as delimited by `;` and finally the `perl` splits each line into 2: one with three fields and one with four.

Comment: thanks, works perfectly. Could you maybe add a short sentence about what the `-F';'` and the `$,=";"` do?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming homogeneous structure of the data you could use GNU sed and GNU awk to accomplish this, e.g.:

```
# Separate records by an extra new-line
sed '2~2G' infile |

# Read records and use GNU awk's built-in sort on field 7
awk '
  BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_desc" }
  { h[$7] = $0 }
  END { for(k in h) print h[k] }
' RS= FS='[;\n]+'
```

Output:

```
a2;b2;c2;
d2;e2;f2;g2
a1;b1;c1;
d1;e1;f1;g1
```