# concatenate n lines with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, sort

Recently, I asked a [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/248250/51034) how to sort pairs of lines, and one of the answers suggested concatenating lines with `sed`, like this:

```
cat file.txt | sed -n 'N;s/\n//;p' | sort -t";" -k43,43n | perl -F';' -ane '$,=";";print @F[0..13],"\n";print @F[14..$#F]'
```

which worked brilliantly, but now my problem generalized to sorting n-tupels of lines, which I can't figure out how to do with sed.

Everything I found was either for 2 lines or ALL lines, but I need n lines (where n is 5 at the moment, but a general way would be great).

Bonus points for a nice way of rewriting the `perl` part to accomodate n lines, but the problem is really about the `sed` part.

I am also not hung on `sed` specifically, so if you have a nice solution using a different command line tool, please post it.

Update: Example input (n == 3)

```
a1;b1;c1; 
n1;m1;l1; 
d1;e1;f1;g1
n2;m2;l2;
a2;b2;c2;
d2;e2;f2;g2
```

Comment: On this type of question it's usual to include a sample input and sample output to illustrate what you want.  It sounds like `perl`'s paragraph mode might be of use here but I'm not sure I get what you're after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -e:n -e$\bo -e'N;s/\n/&/4;to' -ebn -e:o -e'y/\n/ /' <in >out
```

That will concatenate 5 lines - or 1 + 4 lines - replacing each newline with a single space. However:

```
paste -d\  - - - - - <in >out
```

...would also work.

Your `g` sort thing could work like:

```
paste -d\  - - <input   |
sed 's/.*;\(.*\)/\1;&/' |
sort -t\; -k1,1         |
cut  -d\; -f2-          |
tr \  \\n
```

...which would be a fairly general way of doing it, though it relies on there being no spaces in the input file. it joins every two lines on a space, the copies the last `;` split field to the head of each line, sorts on the first field, then cuts it away and splits the lines back out.

Comment: Wow, the combination of `paste` and `tr` is perfect for this problem! So concise! I can't use the `sed` and `cut` trick however, because it is not actually the last field I want to sort on.

Comment: @fifaltra - which field is it? you can do it, you just need to know which field.

Comment: It's field number 26 (on the last line of the n-tuple)

Comment: @fifaltra - well, I guess you don't need it since you know the field number so specifically - so just drop `sed` and `cut` of course. it is a kind of a general solution - if you're ever in a place where sort field is variable, but you can construct a regexp to copy it to the head of the line, remember this.

Comment: In the event that you want more lines concatenated and not hundreds of `-` you can use `xargs -n5 <file` instead of paste, where 5 is the number of lines to be concatenated.

Comment: @User112638726 - that's an entirely different thing. that's an exec of `/bin/echo` for every five input lines. if you don't want to type out hundreds of `-` dashes something like: `set "" - -; while [ "$#" -lt 100 ]; set "$@$@"; done; shift "$(($#-100))"; paste "$@"` or `eval paste "$(printf %100s|sed 's/./- /g')"`

Comment: @User112638726 - one way is handled by a single, simple, fast, utility from start to finish, and another is handled by another utility calling a second utility for every line of output. there might also be problems with quotes, though i don't think that would be an issue here.

Comment: How are your alternatives any better, they call multiple commands as well ? Also where did my other comment go ?

Comment: @User112638726 - that's a good point, but they don't do so *in the loop*. in general - in my experience - it is far better to do a little more work to *prepare* a loop than it is to otherwise do the work *during* the loop. the loop, in this case, is the processing of the input file. in my suggestions the extra stuff only happens the one time to build an argument list for `paste` to afterward take it from there, but with `xargs` you cut up the argument list and distribute it to all of the different `echo` invocations. i dunno about your comment -thought it was weird too. i saw it for a second.

Comment: fair enough :) IMO it is more apparent what the xargs is doing though and is neater, so if resources are abundant then i personally think it is the better choice. Also the original i posted was wrong and split on all [[:space:]] characters. The command should have been `xargs -d'\n' -n5 < file`

Comment: @User112638726 - i would argue that poiunt, too. i dont believe it is apparent that you're calling `echo` for every 5 lines.

Comment: I don't think it is particularly relevant what the underlying mechanics are as long as it doesn't use too much resource, doesn't cause unwanted side effects and produces the output you expect.

Answer (score 1):

With minor modification, you can use the solution [I posted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249670/17666) to your other question.

Again using GNU sed and GNU awk and assuming homogeneous structure of the data, use the last element as the sorting key:

```
# Separate input into records, here 3 lines each
sed '3~3G' infile |

# Use GNU awk's built-in sort, here index-string-descending
awk '
  BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_desc" }
  { h[$NF] = $0 }
  END { for(k in h) print h[k] }
' RS= FS='[;\n]+'
```

Output:

```
n2;m2;l2;
a2;b2;c2;
d2;e2;f2;g2
a1;b1;c1; 
n1;m1;l1; 
d1;e1;f1;g1
```